# Selecting data from tables with laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

Using laravel eloquent to select a specific field value. However, I find myself dealing with this error

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '[{"id":1}]' for column 'department_id' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `opportunities` (`category`, `opportunity`, `vacancies`, `department_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Attachement, Assistant, 2, [{"id":1}], 2017-05-04 02:12:04, 2017-05-04 02:12:04))

field value for department_id should be int, which am drawing from another table as below

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   // return $request->all();

         $this->validate($request,[
        'department'=>'required',
        'category'=>'required',
        'description'=>'required|string',
        'positions'=>'required|integer',
        ]);
    //dd($request); table('departments')->where('dep_name', '$dep')
     $dep = $request->department;
     $department=Department::all();
     //dd($department);

     $department_id = Department::select('id')->where('dep_name','=', $dep)->get();

    // return $department_id;

     $newOpportunity = Opportunity::create(
        [
            'category'=>$request->category,
            'opportunity'=>$request->description,
            'vacancies'=>$request->positions,
            'department_id'=>$department_id,
        ]
        );
     $newOpportunity ->save();

    return redirect('admin/');  
}
```

Comment: change this line 'department_id'=>$department_id[0]->id,

Answer (score 0):

Your passing array as values to derpartment_id column . Id is inside the array you need to access it like this

```
'department_id'=>$department_id[0]->id,
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement

```
Department::select('id')->where('dep_name','=', $dep)->get();
```

returns a `Collection`.

You need the `id` of a single record. Try this

```
$department = Department::where('dep_name','=', $dep)->first();

if($department != null) {
     $newOpportunity = Opportunity::create(
        [
            'category'=>$request->category,
            'opportunity'=>$request->description,
            'vacancies'=>$request->positions,
            'department_id'=>$department->id,
        ]
      );
     $newOpportunity ->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to update your code like:

If you need `id` for single record :

```
 $department_id = Department::where('dep_name','=', $dep)->first();

 $newOpportunity = Opportunity::create(
           [
               'category'=>$request->category,
               'opportunity'=>$request->description,
               'vacancies'=>$request->positions,
               'department_id'=>$department_id->id,
           ]
         );
```

OR you need `id` for multiple record then :

```
 $department_id = Department::select('id')->where('dep_name','=', $dep)->get();

 foreach($department_id as $department_ids){

   $newOpportunity = Opportunity::create(
           [
               'category'=>$request->category,
               'opportunity'=>$request->description,
               'vacancies'=>$request->positions,
               'department_id'=>$department_ids->id,
           ]
         );
 }
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You dont really need the collection. You need single record with one attribute - `id`. 
Your code **very dirty**. Try to **avoid** retrieve unused data like this: `$department=Department::all();`

Code below retrieves from database **ONLY ONE** record, this is right way:

```
$department = Department::select('id')->where('dep_name','=', $request->department)->first();
```

**Full code:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   $this->validate($request,[
        'department' => 'required',
        'category' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required|string',
        'positions' => 'required|integer'
   ]);

   $department = Department::select('id')->where('dep_name','=', $request->department)->first();
   if($department) {
        $newOpportunity = Opportunity::create([
             'category' => $request->category,
             'opportunity' => $request->description,
             'vacancies' => $request->positions,
             'department_id' => $department->id,
        ]);
        $newOpportunity->save();
   }

   return redirect('admin/');  
}
```